# How to get subject_hash (md5) from pem file

Tags: go, openssl

I have a pem file that I am trying to get the subject_has for in Go.

In command line:

```
wmachs-iphone:platform-tools user$ openssl x509 -noout -subject_hash_old -in ../charles-ssl-proxying-certificate.pem
e64b345
```

I've tried using https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/md5/ (no luck, md5 value is different) and https://godoc.org/github.com/spacemonkeygo/openssl==> slight learning curve that I need help on. I tried loading the Pem file but not sure how to get the MD5 portion:

```
pemfile,_ := openssl.LoadCertificateFromPEM(buf.Bytes())
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    regex := regexp.MustCompile("(\n)?-----(.)*-----\n")
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("file.pem")
    parts := regex.ReplaceAllString(string(data), "")
    fmt.Println(parts)
}
```

Comment: @liangusburger Did it help you ?

Comment: No i dont think will get me the MD5 subject_hash

Comment: @liangusburger your question is unclear , what do you mean by md5 subject hash ? the code above returns the portion between -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE----- , Isn't that what you want ? do you want the md5 of that portion ? or what ?

Comment: Sorry as i mentioned, i am looking to get the MD5 of the pem file.  
favorite
I have a pem file that I am trying to get the subject_has for in Go.

The following line gives me the md5: 

wmachs-iphone:platform-tools user$ openssl x509 -noout -subject_hash_old -in ../charles-ssl-proxying-certificate.pem

e64b345

e64b345 is what i want to extract. I am trying to implement this in golang using their libraries.